# expend rows in Antd table with conditions (Antd 3.26.2)

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
<Table pagination={{  pageSize: 30 showSizeChanger: true }}
       scroll={{ x: 500 }}
       dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
       columns={this.props.columns}
       expandedRowRender={record => <p>{record.description}</p>} />
```

I need add condition for this line:

```
expandedRowRender={record => <p>{record.description}</p>}
```

If I have a description for this record I need to expand for this row **(Antd 3.26.2)**
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work around absence of `rowExpandable` in older `AntD` versions by hiding from the user an option to expand the row, using `CSS`.

[Per this suggestion:](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/7817#issuecomment-344143155)

> If you don't want show expand icon for some rows, you can use
> `rowClassName` to add a custom `className` to the row, and hide the expand
> icon by `CSS`.

So in your case:

**YourTable.jsx:**

```
<Table pagination={{  pageSize: 30 showSizeChanger: true }}
       scroll={{ x: 500 }}
       dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
       columns={this.props.columns}
       expandedRowRender={record => <p>{record.description}</p>} 
       rowClassName={(record) => { if (record.description) {
       return "NotExpandible";}}}  />
```

**App.css:**

```
.NotExpandible .ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

[YourTable.jsx file showing table with the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MULvm.png)